# How to choose the correct class encoding approach in classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, classification

I want to perform classification using scikit-learn [MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) using an activity dataset where the class label could be one of following cases:

```
[‘Walk’, ‘Stand’, ‘Run’, ‘Jump’, ‘null’]
```

I am not sure which label encoding approach would be the best here: [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html). I think `LabelEncoder` will be enough since it will represent each case using a single integer value from `1` to `n` but I would like to know if my decision is reasonable.

Thank you

Comment: You can directly send the string targets into MLPClassifier and it will automatically convert them to numerical using LabelEncoder internally automatically as @ely is using. But you dont need to do any that explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LabelEncoder` will work for your use case, using the integers 0 through 4 for class IDs:

```
In [15]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

In [16]: le = LabelEncoder()


In [17]: le.fit(['Walk', 'Stand', 'Run', 'Jump', 'null'])
Out[17]: LabelEncoder()


In [18]: le.classes_
Out[18]: 
array(['Jump', 'Run', 'Stand', 'Walk', 'null'],
      dtype='<U5')

In [19]: le.transform(['null', 'Run', 'Jump'])
Out[19]: array([4, 1, 0])

In [20]: le.inverse_transform([4, 1, 0])
Out[20]: 
array(['null', 'Run', 'Jump'],
      dtype='<U5')
```